# Assignment in elisp

Tags: emacs, variable-assignment, elisp

I'm trying to learn elisp. I wanted to use `(random n)` and then
take the result of `(random n)` and use it to compute a new random
number until we reach 1.

Something like this:

```
(random 100)
99
(random 99)
51
(random 51)
24
(random 24)
11
(random 11)
3
(random 3)
2
(random 2)
1
```

How do I assign, the new value of `n` to `(random n)` ?

`(setq n (random n))`

does not work. This gives a constant number, `(random n)` is not calculated.

Can you give me a hint? I realize this is a total newbie question. Thanks.

**EDİT**

```
(defun rnd (n)       
  (setq counter 0)
  (let ((ret ()))
            
    (while (< 1 n)
      
      (setq n (random n))
      (setq counter (+ counter 1))  
      (push n ret))
    
    
    (reverse ret))
  )

(format "list: %s \n steps: %s" (rnd 100000) counter)
```

Comment: That works for me when I evaluate it in `*scratch*`. How are you determining the value of `n`?

Comment: I'm trying to do something like this : (defun rnd (n)
  (setq n (random n))
  ...
    )

Comment: and call like this (rnd 100)

Comment: You're assigning to the function's parameter, which has no effect on whatever you passed to the function. (Do you expect `(rnd 100)` to modify the value of 100?)

Comment: By the way, please read about the [mcve].

Comment: Since the function `rnd` that I defined takes one argument, I thought the initial value of `n` will be `100` if I do `(rnd 100). Then I want the function to compute (random n) for `n=100` and return a new random number. Then I want to take the new random number and compute `(random n)` again, until `(random n) returns `1`

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'm reading.

Comment: @zeynel: you need some form of recursion, or iteration. Either call `(rnd (random n))` recursively or use a `while` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the value of an external variable from within a function:

```
(defvar n 100)
(defun rnd (n)
  (setq n (random n)))
```

`(rnd n)` will *not* change the value of `n` because `rnd` create a new binding for `n`.

This, however, should work:

```
(defvar n 100)
(defun rnd ()
  (setq n (random n)))
```

Or you can just do a loop inside `rnd`:

```
(defun rnd (n)
  (let ((ret ()))
    (while (< 1 n)
      (setq n (random n))
      (push n ret))
    ret))
(rnd 100)
==> (1 3 8 16 20 27 53)
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess you used `let` because it defines local variables? Why is all the code that comes after `let` is inside the `let`?

Comment: @zeynel: because `ret` is not defined outside `let`

Comment: "list: (34126 16061 1041 276 218 115 9 0) 
 steps: 8"
Why does (random n) sometimes return `0`? I would think it should stop at `1`

Comment: @zeynel: read the doc for `random`. that's how it is defined.